# What are the falsy values in Bash?

Tags: bash

As the title states, I would like to know all the falsy values in Bash. It seems like the number 1 is considered false in Bash. Is that correct? Are there any other values that evaluate to false in a boolean context in Bash?

Comment: In what context do you see 1 considered to be false?

Comment: ‘_boolean context in Bash_’ I don’t know of any such context. Could you provide som examples?

Comment: Could it be that you're thinking about the _exit status_ a program ends with? In that case 0 by convention means success, while >0 indicates some sort of failure.

Answer (score 3):

It depends *completely* on context. Shell syntax and semantics are highly context-dependent, and this is no exception.

In the context of an exit status, 0 is truthy and anything nonzero is falsy:

```
$ (exit 0) && echo true || echo false
true
$ (exit 1) && echo true || echo false
false
```

(Note that I'm using `&&` and `||` as a shorthand for `if ... then ... else... fi` -- this can fail in weird ways, and shouldn't be used unless you understand its potential oddities.)

But in an arithmentic context, it's the exact opposite:

```
$ ((0)) && echo true || echo false
false
$ ((1)) && echo true || echo false
true
```

(BTW, the `(( ))` command-like-thing essentially "runs" an arithmetic expression as a command, and *converts the result from arithmetic semantics to exit-status semantics*. Thus, `((0))` has an exit status of 1, and `((1))` and `((15000))` both have an exit status of 0. Yes, this is confusing.)

And just to be even more difficult, in an arithmetic context, words will be treated as variable names and evaluated in hopes that they'll yield integers. If they're undefined/blank, that's treated as "0", which is falsy:

```
$ ((true)) && echo true || echo false
false
$ ((false)) && echo true || echo false
false
$ ((wibble)) && echo true || echo false
false
$ ((HOME)) && echo true || echo false
-bash: ((: /Users/gordon: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/Users/gordon")
false
```

And in a `[ ]` test, *any* number will be truthy (an empty string would be falsy in that context):

```
$ [ 0 ] && echo true || echo false
true
$ [ 1 ] && echo true || echo false
true
$ [ "" ] && echo true || echo false
false
$ [ ] && echo true || echo false
false
$ [ true ] && echo true || echo false
true
$ [ false ] && echo true || echo false
true
$ [ wibble ] && echo true || echo false
true
$ [ HOME ] && echo true || echo false
true
```

So you can't make any general statement at all about what's truthy vs falsy without specifying what context you're using it in.

Answer (score 2):

The only data type in bash is the string. There are no booleans. Consequently, conditional operations (`if`, `&&`, `||`) don't operate on **explicit** values, but on exit codes. For instance

```
if p
then
  echo true
fi
```

takes the *then* branch if p terminates with the exit code zero. Only in **that** respect, 0 could be regarded as "kind of True", and any other integral value (1..255) could be regarded as "kind of False".